# Can we optionally use `JSON Path` in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-server-json

I want to return JSON or a Table result set (normal) based on a parameter that I am passing to a SQL Server stored procedure.

```
SELECT  
    emp.Name,
    emp.EmpID 
FROM 
    Employee emp 
ORDER BY 
    emp.Name       
FOR JSON Path;
```

This will return one column with a string JSON result.

I want to make this optional based on a parameter. Basically I want to re-use the stored procedure for JSON as well as normal result.

Comment: Won't checking the parameter and duplicating the body work ..some thing like ..if @parameter is null begin normal result end if @paramerter=something begin json result end

Answer (score 0):

Sql key words or objects name ie  column name or table name can not be used  directly  as parameter,

You have and alternate write dynamic SQL in side SP.

Note: It will have performance hit as it is dynamic SQL.

suggestion: Write two sp .